# Why does a semi-transparent background shine through in a different div

Tags: html, css, alpha, rgba

I have a page with 3 elements. One in the center, with a nice background image; overlayed onto this, is a 2nd div which has a black semi-transparent background to better be able to read the text inside it.

Aside from that, I also have a floating div with a completely white background.

For some odd reason, when the float overlays the semi-transparent div, the semi-transparent backgound seems to bleed through into the float.

My HTML + CSS to demonstrate my problem. If you make your browser window smaller, the right float will move towards the center div. It will properly stay red, except for the place where it hits the alpha-inset.

Why??

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#centerDiv {
   height: 300px;
   width: 900px;
   margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
   padding: 0 0;
   background-color: green;
}
#centerInset {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   position: relative;
   top: 225px;
   height: 74px;
   color: white;
}
#floater {
   float: right;
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 1px solid;
   clear: both;
   background-color: rgba(250,0,0,1);
   border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="floater">
   <span>some floating text</span>
</div>
<div id="centerDiv">
   <div id="centerInset"><span>Some random text</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good question: I just tried with `z-index` and it is still the same!?!

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with z-index as well, also tried setting a opacity property to force the float to full opacity. But nothing changed.
Odd thing is, this same "bug" appears to be present in the latest firefox, safari, chrome (yes, I know it's also webkit, like safari) and IE versions. So I would gather it's something in the standards, and not implementation-specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `z-index` + `position` to make z-index work -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fPw5H/)

Comment: Ah, thanks for that! Apparently it matters whether position is static (default) or relative. Only in relative does it bother looking at z-index.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it could be something like that : When you make "centerInset" relative, z-index is relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.

If you make "centerDiv" position relative, it'll work like you expect.